# Extension not showing in admin but can be seen in System > Config > Advanced

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, extensions

It is a bit weird that my extensions don't show in admin. Below are my files:

> etc/modules/Company_GoogleAnalytics.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

true
            local

> config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_GoogleAnalytics>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_GoogleAnalytics>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <googleanalytics>
                <rewrite>
                    <ga>Company_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga</ga>
                </rewrite>
            </googleanalytics>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

> system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <google>
            <groups>
                <analytics>
                    <fields>
                        <enable_code1 translate="label">
                            <label>Enable Code 1</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>110</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </enable_code1>
                        <code1 translate="label">
                            <label>Method Code 1</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>111</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </code1>
                        <enable_code2 translate="label">
                            <label>Enable Code 2</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>120</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </enable_code2>
                        <code2 translate="label">
                            <label>Code 2</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>121</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </code2>
                        <enable_code3 translate="label">
                            <label>Enable Code 3</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>130</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </enable_code3>
                        <code3 translate="label">
                            <label>Code 3</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>131</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </code3>
                        <enable_code4 translate="label">
                            <label>Enable Code 4</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>140</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </enable_code4>
                        <code4 translate="label">
                            <label>Code 4</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>141</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </code4>
                        <enable_code5 translate="label">
                            <label>Enable Code 5</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>150</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </enable_code5>
                        <code5 translate="label">
                            <label>Code 5</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>151</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </code5>
                    </fields>
                </freeshipping>
            </groups>
        </carriers>
    </sections>
</config>
```

> EXTENSION_PATH/Block/Ga.php

```
<?php
class Company_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga extends Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga
{
    protected function _getPageTrackingCodeAnalytics( $accountId )
    {
        $pageName   = trim($this->getPageName());
        $optPageURL = '';
        if ($pageName && preg_match('/^\/.*/i', $pageName)) {
            $optPageURL = ", '{$this->jsQuoteEscape($pageName)}'";
        }
        return "
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '{$this->jsQuoteEscape($accountId)}']);
    " . $this->_getAnonymizationCode() . "
    $this->_getExtraCode()
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview'{$optPageURL}]);
    ";
    }

    protected function _getExtraCode()
    {
        $extraCode = '';
        for ( $i = 1; $i <= 5; $i ++ ) {
            if ( Mage::getStoreConfig('google/analytics/enable_code' . $i) ) {
                $extraCode .= rtrim( Mage::getStoreConfig('google/analytics/code' . $i), ';' ) . ';';
            }
        }
        return $extraCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try  clear cache & logout and login from backend.....

Comment: All cache are disabled, I also logged out and logged in to try but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yor XML closing tags aren't correct.

Please replace:

```
                </freeshipping>
            </groups>
        </carriers>
    </sections>
</config>
```

With:

```
                </analytics>
            </groups>
        </google>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. Super thanks and have a nice day @sv3n.